# Applying a function ordinal number of times

Tags: ordinals

I'm taking an introductory topology course and the idea of the ordinal numbers was very briefly introduced in class. I was wondering what determines whether function application can be done an ordinal number of times.

More formally, define the nesting function $N(f,x,a)$ -- where $f:X\rightarrow X$, $x\in X$ and $a$ is an ordinal number -- as follows:

- If $a=0$, then $N(f,x,a) = x$.
- If $a$ has an immediate predecessor, $N(f,x,a) = f(N(f,x,\mathrm{pred}(a)))$
- Otherwise (i.e., if $a$ is a limit ordinal) then how do you sensibly define $N(f,x,a)$?

What would be the necessary and sufficient conditions so that one can make a "sensible" definition for $N$? For example, I would naively expect that for $X=\{0,1\}$ and $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$, one might not be able to make such a definition (what would $N(f,0,\omega)$ be?). On the other hand, if $X$ is the set of all ordinals and $f$ is the usual successor function, I think that $N$ can probably be suitably defined.

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409562/derivatives-of-ordinal-order . The author there talks about applying derivatives an ordinal number of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to iterate a function transfinite times?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905712/is-it-possible-to-iterate-a-function-transfinite-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key property you're looking for is *convergence* in an appropriate sense: if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and $a_\alpha$ is a sequence in some space $X$ for $\alpha<\lambda$, say $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}\rightarrow b$ ($b\in X$) if for every open set $U\ni b$, there is some $\beta<\lambda$ such that $a_\alpha\in U$ for every $\alpha>\beta$. If such a $b$ exists *and is unique* (if our space is Hausdorff we don't need to specify uniqueness - exercise!), say the sequence $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ is *convergent*.

For example, the $\omega$-sequence $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, . . .$ is not convergent (at least, assuming the usual topology on $\{0, 1\}$). Meanwhile, looking at the ordinals with their usual topology (the order topology), we see that the sequence $a_\alpha=\alpha$ ($\alpha<\lambda$) converges to $\lambda$; this meets the intuition that if I apply successor an ordinal number of times to $0$, I should get that ordinal back.

Some caution is needed, however: consider the maps $f:\alpha\mapsto \alpha$ (identity) and $g:\alpha\mapsto 2\alpha$ (doubling) on the ordinals. Then we have $f^\omega(0)=\omega=g^\omega(0)$, even though as $n\rightarrow\omega$ the "gap" between $f^n(0)$ and $g^n(0)$ gets larger and larger! So our intuitions aren't always great at figuring out how ordinally-iterated maps behave.

*In fact, there's a more general theorem lurking here: if $h$ is an* increasing continuous *function from ordinals to ordinals, then there are many ordinals $\alpha$ such that $h(\alpha)=\alpha$. A keyword here is **club** (= closed unbounded set of ordinals), and as you go further you'll also wind up caring about **stationary** sets of ordinals ($A$ is stationary if $A\cap C\not=\emptyset$ for every club $C$; think of clubs as being "big," and stationary sets as being "not small").*

Comment: Re: big vs. not small, you can think of this as in analogy with measure $1$ versus not measure zero.

Comment: That is almost on point apart from one catch; we would need that every time the sequence converges to precisely one point, no more, no less.

Comment: @theindigamer You're right, I was tacitly assuming the spaces in question were Hausdorff; fixed.

Comment: I understood your answer but not the measure analogy in the comment.

Comment: @theindigamer Are you familiar with measure theory?

Comment: I think I have a rough understanding of the analogy now. However, it is not immediately obvious that stationary sets cannot be made "sparse enough" to be analogous to measure 0 sets. Maybe I just need to think it over a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @theindigamer The analogue of a measure zero set here is a co-club: a set whose complement is club. No stationary set can be co-club, since no stationary set intersects its own complement. (Continuing the analogy: we can show that the intersection of two clubs is club, while there *are* disjoint stationary sets!)

Comment: That is really interesting! :D