# Closed form for $\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, nested-radicals

Nested squares seem to be more promising than nested radicals, since they give rational approximations and in principle can be expanded into a series.

These two expressions converge numerically:

$$\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=2.14842827808221794391178636615$$

$$\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{4}-\cdots\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=0.680484597688804927729801584438$$

Search with ISC, Wolframalpha and OEIS did not reveal any closed forms for these numbers.

> Is it possible that a closed form exists for these nested squares and how would you go about finding it?

The proper definition for the first nested square is the limit of the sequence:

$$s_1=1$$

$$s_2=\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)^2$$

$$s_3=\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2$$

Etc. The same for the second nested square.

---

Other two (alternating) expressions:

$$\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\cdots\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=1.27629973953623486796358849410$$

$$\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2=0.462513422693928495067300679614$$

Again, I found nothing on these numbers.

If you know any reference about nested squares in general, it would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the expression can be expressed as $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\LARGE\mathrm F}} \ (\frac{1}{n}+x)^2$

Comment: @Jacob What does the large F denote?

Comment: Has anyone observed anything between $S_+$ and $S_-$? That might help in computation

Comment: @user236182 This post should help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224411/this-one-weird-thing-that-bugs-me-about-summation-and-the-like

Comment: Helpful or not...I'm not too sure. Consider the expression  $$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\left(\frac{1}{x+n}+\cdots\right)^2=\frac1x + F^2(x+n)$$

Comment: since you know the numerical value, you can use experimental mathematics software (i guess even online, for free) to match combinations of known constants to your numerical result. Maybe one of them matches to all digits, and you stumbled on the closed form, albeit without proof...

Comment: @Chip The Inverse Symbolic Calculator (ISC as mentioned by OP) is indeed one of the types of software you are describing.

Comment: @ErickWong: thanks for sharing. Maybe Yuriy S would give it a try and find the answer...

Comment: @Chip Did you not read the question?

Comment: @ErickWong: can you clarify? The question is looking for a closed form for which exact numerical result is available. And the latter could be matched maybe by an experimental mathematics software as the one you quote...

Comment: @Chip Sure, no problem.  As I stated earlier, the OP describes having already used said software and not finding a match.

Comment: @ErickWong: oh, thats what you meant. I was not aware of what the "ISC, Wolframalpha and OEIS" meant, nor "OP" lol..Could you write down their meanings? Thanks.

Comment: PS: Wolframalpha needs no explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38839/discussion-between-chip-and-erick-wong).

Comment: Ahhh, that explains the confusion.  OP means original post (or original poster if referring to the person rather than the content).  ISC is Inverse Symbolic Calculator, and OEIS is Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: The sequence $(s_i)=\left(1, \frac{25}{16}, \frac{198025}{104976}, \frac{57723297832225}{28179280429056}, \frac{1388242952828865742239767175430685281}{656100000000000000000000000000000000},\ldots\right)$ does not have its numerators or denominators in the OEIS either.

Answer (score 5):

Using the idea by [TylerHG](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/130642/tylerhg), we can approach the inner (infinity) part of expression to accelerate the convergence of the consequences. For the first sequence can be considered a function
$$f(x) = \dfrac1{x+n}+f^2(x+1),\qquad(1)$$
or
$$f(x-1) = \dfrac1{x+n-1} + f^2(x).$$
For $x\in[n-1,n]$ function $f(x)$ can be represented by Taylor series with sufficient accuracy, so
$$f(x-1)\approx f(x)-f'(x)+\dfrac{f''(x)}2-\dfrac{f'''(x)}6+\dfrac{f^{(IV)}}{24}(x)-\dfrac{f^{(V)}(x)}{120}+\dfrac{f^{(VI)}(x)}{720}-\dots.$$
For arbitrary values of $x$ convenient to use the type of expansion
$$f(x)=\dfrac1{x+n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{a_1}{x+n-1}+\dfrac{a_2}{(x+n-1)^2}+\dfrac{a_3}{(x+n-1)^3}+\dfrac{a_4}{(x+n-1)^4}+\dfrac{a_5}{(x+n-1)^5}+\dfrac{a_6}{(x+n-1)^6}+\dots\right),$$
then
$$f^2(x) = \dfrac1{(x+n-1)^2}\left(1+\dfrac{2a_1}{x+n-1} + \dfrac{2a_2+a_1^2}{(x+n-1)^2} + \dfrac{2a_3+2a_1a_2}{(x+n-1)^3}\\+ \dfrac{2a_4+2a_1a_3+a_2^2}{(x+n-1)^4}+ \dfrac{2a_5+2a_1a_4+2a_2a_3}{(x+n-1)^5} + \dots\right),$$
$$-f'(x)=\dfrac1{(x+n-1)^2}\left(1+\dfrac{2a_1}{x+n-1}+\dfrac{3a_2}{(x+n-1)^2}+\dfrac{4a_3}{(x+n-1)^3}\\+\dfrac{5a_4}{(x+n-1)^4}+\dfrac{6a_5}{(x+n-1)^5}+\dots\right),$$
$$f''(x)=\dfrac1{(x+n-1)^3}\left(2+\dfrac{6a_1}{x+n-1}+\dfrac{12a_2}{(x+n-1)^2}+\dfrac{20a_3}{(x+n-1)^3}\\+\dfrac{30a_4}{(x+n-1)^4}+\dots\right),$$
$$-f'''(x)=\dfrac1{(x+n-1)^4}\left(6+\dfrac{24a_1}{x+n-1}+\dfrac{60a_2}{(x+n-1)^2}+\dfrac1{120}\dfrac{120a_3}{(x+n-1)^3}+\dots\right),$$
$$f^{IV}(x)=\dfrac1{(x+n-1)^5}\left(24+\dfrac{120a_1}{x+n-1}+\dfrac{360a_2}{(x+n-1)^2}+\dots\right),$$
$$-f^{V}(x)=\dfrac1{(x+n-1)^6}\left(120+\dfrac{720a_1}{x+n-1}+\dots\right),$$
$$f^{VI}(x)=\dfrac{720}{(x+n-1)^7}+\dots.$$
So we have:
$$\begin{cases}
a_1+1 = 1\\
a_2+2a_1+1 = 2a_1\\
a_3+3a_2+3a_1+1 = 2a_2+a_1^2\\
a_4+4a_3+6a_2+4a_1+1 = 2a_3+a_1a_2\\
a_5+5a_4+10a_3+10a_2+5a_1+1 = 2a_4+2a_1a_3+a_2^2\\
a_6+6a_5+15a_4+20a_3+15a_2+6a_1+1 = 2a_5 + 2a_1a_4+2a_2a_3,\\
a_7+7a_6+21a_5+35a_4+35a_5+21a_1+7a_1+1 = 2a_6 + 2a_1a_5 + 2a_2a_4+a_3^2,
\end{cases}$$

from whence
$$a_1=0;\quad a_2=-1,\quad a_3=0,\quad a_4=5,\quad a_5=-5,\quad a_6=-41,\quad a_7 = 145,$$
$$f(x)=\dfrac1{x+n-1} - \dfrac{1}{(x+n-1)^3}+\dfrac{5}{(x+n-1)^5}-\dfrac{5}{(x+n-1)^6}+\dfrac{-41}{(x+n-1)^7}+\dfrac{145}{(x+n-1)^8}+\dots.$$

Using the series obtained in the form of
$$f(n)=\dfrac1n - \dfrac{1}{n^3}+\dfrac{5}{n^5}-\dfrac{5}{n^6}-\dfrac{41}{n^7}+\dfrac{145}{n^8}+\dots.$$
for calculating the supplement to the internal fractions (an infinite amount)
significally increasing convergence of the original sequence.

Test results [for](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((((((145%2F8-41)%2F8-5)%2F8%2B5)%2F64-1)%2F64%2B1)%2F8)%5E2) $n = 8,$ [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B(1%2F2%2B(1%2F3%2B(1%2F4%2B(1%2F5%2B(1%2F6%2B(1%2F7%2B(1%2F8%2B0.015170721236)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2)%5E2) $2.148428280400...,$ and this value approximates the limit $2.148428278082218...$ of first consequence with great precision.

When using the values n <8 resulting formula is a less accurate, but shorter.

Comment: Usually closed form means closed form ie expressing it as combinations of rationale and known irrationals.. Considering an approximation a "closed form" isn't really satisfactory. Of course, it can be useful nonetheless

Comment: @Ant formulas for $f(8)$ and resulting formula are closed and contains only the 4 arithmetic operations. I broke them into two parts, so that the result could be seen in Wolfram Alpha

Comment: $f(8)$ is an infinite series, right?  Not a closed form.

Comment: @GEdgar, $f(8)$ was calculated as sum of seven fractions. Without it we have $2.147935291824$.

Comment: If it is not an _exact_ expression for the original limiting value, it is not a 'closed form' for that value of the original series.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I remove the words "closed form"